# How to add custom button in django-admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-admin

I have a another submit button in change_form and if this button clickled i want to validate and customize my requested data.

*admin.py*

```
 def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    data = request.GET.copy()
    if '_saveandclose' in request.POST:
        data['CloseDetail'] = "Save and Closed Clicked!"


    obj.User = request.user
    obj.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

For documentation purposes I've created a more complete version of @Radishx's solution. This will add a publish button in `QuestionAdmin`.

*settings.py*

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['backend/templates'],  # Search in backend app first to overwrite admin
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

*backend/templates/admin/submit_line.html*

```
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
<div class="submit-row">
{% block submit-row %}
{% if show_save %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save">{% endif %}
{% if show_delete_link %}
    {% url opts|admin_urlname:'delete' original.pk|admin_urlquote as delete_url %}
    <p class="deletelink-box"><a href="{% add_preserved_filters delete_url %}" class="deletelink">{% trans "Delete" %}</a></p>
{% endif %}
{% if show_save_as_new %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save as new' %}" name="_saveasnew">{% endif %}
{% if show_save_and_add_another %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and add another' %}" name="_addanother">{% endif %}
{% if show_save_and_continue %}<input type="submit" value="{% if can_change %}{% trans 'Save and continue editing' %}{% else %}{% trans 'Save and view' %}{% endif %}" name="_continue">{% endif %}
{% if show_publish %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Publish' %}" class="default" name="_publish">{% endif %}
{% if show_close %}<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' %}" class="closelink">{% trans 'Close' %}</a>{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Notice the `{% if show_publish %}`.

*backend/admin.py*

```
@admin.register(Question)
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        try:
            extra_context['show_publish'] = True
        except TypeError:
            extra_context = {'show_publish': True}
        return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

Change `backend` to your app name.
After this, you have to make sure that Django knows what to do with a _publish button.

Answer (score 1):

1.copy the `/your_python_path/python_version/site-packages/lib/django/crontab/admin/template` to your project and add TEMPLATE config to your settings
(u can also edit it in your venv without copy to your proj)

2.then edit `your_proj/template/admin/submit_line.html` ,add/modify some `<input>/<button>` as you wish

e.x. `<button class="default" onclick="xxxx" > sth </button>`

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a new button to an admin template(ie. admin/change_form.html), you have to [override the admin template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates) and add a custom `submit_buttons_bottom` block. A template tag is used to render the default submit buttons, you can add your custom button and styling here.

```
{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}{% submit_row %}{% endblock %}
```